# Programming string in math

Tags: formal-languages

It seems that everything in programming is relatated to some math theory even regular expressions, but what about strings. Is there simple "thing" in math that can be equivalent of a string in programming language? And I don't want answer about languages, alphabets and grammars in math, which I think it's not the "thing" I need.

Comment: Sorry but I was not able to find any good tag, and I can't create one.

Comment: Strings are called "words" in formal languages. Check out [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_language).

Comment: @AymanHourieh is there something else, is language theory new thing? Is subset of alphabets (words) the "thing". I thought that language theory is new thing.

Comment: A string in programming language is an array of characters. Depending on the encoding, a character is some number of bytes. I guess bytes are numbers so they're mathematical... Other than that, don't understand the question.

Comment: @jcubic I don't understand the question. What do you mean by language theory? If you're looking for the analogue of string in formal languages, then it's called a word.

Comment: @Shahar you can say that drawing on canvas is mathematical because canvas is created from pixels and pixels are RGB which are bytes which are numbers. But vector drawing is based on geometry, even canvas have x and y.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strings of symbols are fundamental in logic (and of course in formal language theory), but they usually don't get a very formal treatment in themselves. Usually the reader is supposed to know *intuitively* how they work.

If you do want to be formal about strings themselves (rather than the *sets* of strings that formal language theory is mostly concerned with), the most "dignified" mathematical structure may be that of a *free monoid* over an alphabet, to which some concept from abstract algebra can be applied.

But you're probably not going to reach anything *deep* about strings this way.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was asking because I'm writing a book about programming and math (for hight school kids with selected math from college) and I decide to skip strings, since I don't need them to connect math with programming, but I'm not sure. I think that I should include them but I don't want to say anything about something that's complex. And I shouldn't say that they don't have they math equvalent because that will be not true.

Comment: Of course the string occuring in `print "Hello world!"` hardly reminds us of free monoids ...

Comment: @jcubic: Well, from the programming side, strings are really neither more nor less than a special case of the general idea of a _finite sequence_, which has been blessed with special syntax and (sometimes) short operators for purely pragmatic reasons. And of course finite sequences are _used_ all over mathematics, but that doesn't mean there's anything particularly interesting to say _about_ them in themselves.